# Как спарсить тег с плавающим расположением на php?

Tags: php, парсер

Использую PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser для получения информации со страницы. Не могу спарсить содержимое тегов, так как у них нет четкого расположения. Он может идти вторым, может быть пятым, а может быть и первым, единственное за что можно зацепиться, так это его расположение после следующей конструкции:     `<p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>`

```
// Пример 1
     <div class=primer>
     <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>   
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне нужен</div>
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также нужен</div>
     </div>

// Пример 2
     <div class=primer>
     <p class="oposit part1 part2">Наименования</p> 
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
     <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне нужен</div>
     <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также нужен</div>
     </div>

// Пример 3
    <div class=primer>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Заметка</p>   
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Наименования</p>  
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также нужен</div>
</div>

// Пример 4
    <div class=primer>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Заметка</p>   
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Наименования</p>  
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">История</p>   
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
</div>
```

Можно ли, например, с помощью регулярки, указать парсеру, на расположение необходимых тегов?
Если есть другой способ решить задачу, прошу предложить его.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение, примерно, выглядит так:

```
<?php
include "simple_html_dom.php";

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<html><body>    <div class=primer>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Заметка</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Наименования</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также нужен</div>
    <p class="oposit part1 part2">История</p>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне не нужен</div>
    <div class="halfM indPar">Текст, который мне также не нужен</div>
    </div></body></html>');

$ret = $html->find('p[class=oposit part1 part2]');
foreach ($ret as $element) {
    if ($element->plaintext == 'Примечание') {
        $next = $element;
        while (($next = $next->next_sibling()) && $next->class == 'halfM indPar') {
            echo $next->plaintext . "<br>\n";
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Выведет на всех 4х примерах:

```
Текст, который мне нужен
Текст, который мне также нужен
```

**Примечание:** Если на странице в нужных вам элементах будут переставлены классы или добавлены символы (пробелы например) в перечисление классов, то этот код не сработает.

Comment: Благодарю. Решил для себя усложнить ситуацию, добавил еще несколько <p class="oposit part1 part2">Примечание</p> и дивов после него, исправил break на continue, чтобы продолжал искать, добавил контроль количества дивов <div class="halfM indPar"> не более 2 и вывел данные в массив, но вот незадача при echo данные показываются нормально, а вот массив дублируется, да еще и контроль количества не работает. Есть идеи, что я сделал не так? https://jsfiddle.net/g9sq9rnx/5/